# Model not saving Paperclip avatar data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, uri

I have a Rails 4 app that scrapes a given web page and saves the data in a `Link` model.

I'm using the Paperclip gem in conjunction with the `after_save` callback to get the url of the image and then upload it to AWS S3. This all works fine and I can view the image in my S3 bucket.

The problem I have is that the `avatar_file_name`, `avatar_content_type`, `avatar_file_size` and `avatar_updated_at` columns in the db remain `nil` as if there is no `:avatar` attached the the `Link`

`link.rb:`

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :picture_from_url

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

...

    def picture_from_url
      self.avatar = URI.parse(self.image_url)
    end

end
```

UPDATE: with Controller code

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

...

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.create(link_params)
    if @link.save
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for your submission!"
        redirect_to link_path(@link)
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def link_params
    params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url, :content, :tag_list, :category, :image_url, :avatar).merge(user_id: current_user.id, author_first_name: current_user.first_name)
  end

end
```

Comment: could you show us the `controller` and `view`

Comment: I've added details from the LinksController but as you can see it's all pretty standard stuff. I'm not having any trouble scraping the web page and saving the data in the Link model to begin with, I'm just having trouble saving the avatar data after the Link has been saved

Comment: Also, I'm not currently using the data in the view

Comment: Can you confirm that using the printing `link.avata.url` prints the right image url? For the `nil` values paperclip somehow should detect the file's properties, but I can't see where you accessing the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

`Link` wasn't getting the updated `avatar` information because the data wasn't being persisted by any kind of save action. So if I do:

```
def picture_from_url
  self.avatar = URI.parse(self.image_url)
  self.save
end
```

Everything works nicely. Would be great to get some feedback on calling `self.save` inside my model. It smells to me.